# DI Scope in Microsoft Graph example: aspnetcore-connect-sample

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

The code for this example includes the following in startup.cs

```
 services.AddSingleton<IGraphAuthProvider, GraphAuthProvider>(); 
 services.AddTransient<IGraphSdkHelper, GraphSdkHelper>();
```

an I'm wondering why the GraphSdkHelper is scoped to be transient, particularly since it looks like the salient class in GraphSdkHelper is new'ed on each request anyway.

```
/* 
*  Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license. 
*  See LICENSE in the source repository root for complete license information. 
*/

using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Microsoft.Graph;

namespace MicrosoftGraphAspNetCoreConnectSample.Helpers
{
    public class GraphSdkHelper : IGraphSdkHelper
    {
        private readonly IGraphAuthProvider _authProvider;
        private GraphServiceClient _graphClient;

        public GraphSdkHelper(IGraphAuthProvider authProvider)
        {
            _authProvider = authProvider;
        }

        // Get an authenticated Microsoft Graph Service client.
        public GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient(string userId)
        {
            _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                async requestMessage =>
                {
                    // Passing tenant ID to the sample auth provider to use as a cache key
                    var accessToken = await _authProvider.GetUserAccessTokenAsync(userId);

                    // Append the access token to the request
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                    // This header identifies the sample in the Microsoft Graph service. If extracting this code for your project please remove.
                    requestMessage.Headers.Add("SampleID", "aspnetcore-connect-sample");
                }));

            return _graphClient;
        }
    }
    public interface IGraphSdkHelper
    {
        GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient(string userId);
    }
}
```

Comment: The usual decision tree for dependency lifetimes is like this: Always use transient, unless you need to keep state scoped in which case you make it scoped, unless you need to keep state permanently in which case you use singleton. – So I assume that `GraphAuthProvider` is having some persistent state, which explains why it’s singleton. And everything else is transient per default.

Comment: really, transient seems rather inefficient, particularly since there is no state whatsoever

Comment: Why inefficient? Object creation is fast, and in this particular example, there’s actually nothing happening at creation that would warrant lifetime management for this simple dependency.

Comment: it's somewhat pedantic, but in this case there is essentially no state to keep, so why not make it a singleton

Comment: I suspect `GraphAuthProvider` leverages `HttpClient` and is a singleton to avoid the connection overhead cost: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/